# Angular2 EventEmitter doesn't raise event when emitted in a callback

Tags: angular

I'm developing an Angular2 component which uses the webcam to snap a picture to a canvas element, and extract it as a `Blob`. Seperately, the `Blob` and the event work correctly, but when I try to emit the event from within `toBlob`'s callback function, the event is no longer raised for its listeners.

This works:

```
var self = this;

self.gotSnapshot.emit({}); //Raises the gotSnapshot event correctly.

this.canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
  console.log(blob); //Logs the blob to console correctly.
});
```

This doesn't:

```
var self = this;

this.canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
  self.gotSnapshot.emit(blob); //Event is never raised for listeners
});
```

I'm sure it's because `toBlob` is executing asynchronously. In Angular1 my instinct would be to do a $timeout and call apply, but I thought for an EventEmitter we don't have to deal with all that anymore?

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This API is not patched by Angulars zone. You need to explicitly make the code run in Angulars zone for change detection to happen afterwards:

```ts
constructor(private zone:NgZone){}

someMethod() {
  this.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.gotSnapshot.emit(blob); 
    });
  });
}
```

You also don't need `self` if you use `() =>` instead of `function()`

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks very much that was exactly what I needed. I guess it's time to go and learn all about this 'zone' thing I've been hearing about.